# Drawing an image in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to just draw a simple image from the drawable-mdpi folder in android but I keep getting an error saying droid_1 cannot be resolved or is not a field, droid_1 is the name of the image, this is my code,

thanks for any help.

```
import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

public class GameView extends View {
    private Bitmap bmp;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.droid_1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the eclipse plugin for Android downs't always pick up new or changed resources correctly.  Try refreshing your project in the Project Explorer view or a clean from the Project menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "import android.R;" to "import "import com.your.package.R;" where com.your.package is your package name...

Answer (score 0):

You are importing android.R the android.R file won't contain your resources

Answer (score 0):

You say that your image is in the drawable-mdpi folder. If you aren't using an MDPI display, Android won't be able to find an image to show on the screen. Make sure you have an image in each of the drawable-... folders, or a single image in the drawable folder, so that at least it will be able to find an image to use regardless of the screen resolution.

Also, you're trying to import the standard android.R package. Try removing this import line completely and let Eclipse suggest the correct R package to import - it'll be something like `import com.yourapp.R;`